# What happened to method ViewCompat.setActivated()?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I try to use Android Support Library, revision 23.1.0 (October 2015). The problem is that in a simple line:

```
ViewCompat.setActivated(myView, true);
```

I get the syntax error:

> The method setActivated(View, boolean) is undefined for the type ViewCompat

I looked up the docs at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setActivated%28android.view.View,%20boolean%29

and this method should cleary be available. Excerpt form the docs:

> public static void setActivated (View view, boolean activated)
>
> Changes the activated state of this view. A view can be activated or not. Note that activation is not the same as selection. Selection is a transient property, representing the view (hierarchy) the user is currently interacting with. Activation is a longer-term state that the user can move views in and out of.
>   Parameters
>   activated   true if the view must be activated, false otherwise

I need this method. Is this a mistake in android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat or have I missed something?

Comment: Make sure that you have imported the v4 support library and that you are using android.support.v4.View

Comment: I am sure, Otherwise the type ViewCompat would not be available.

Comment: it should be no problem with it, maybe clean/rebuild your module?

Comment: Maybe its a different ViewCompat class from a different support library, im seeing that method in Android studio autocomplete list without any problem...

Comment: try removing your support v4 jar from your project and add it again from sdk extras

Comment: try to make clean project, build project, look at your gradle dependecy version of support-v4. If persist, execute the app in debug, put breakpoint on the line affected and when you are there right click and click on "Evaluate expression". Type "ViewCompat". Then try exploring the "setActivated" and see what you got.

Comment: @Nanoc Could you please look up thge support library version and exact app-compat-v4.jat file length?

Comment: im using gradle to import it: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'

Comment: @Nanoc. I am afraid you did not understand. You have to locate the aforementioned file and look up the file propertied and get exact byte length. But from your gradle I suspect you are using different version.

Comment: Yes, im not using a jar, just that line on the gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use Android support library app-compat-v7 set up as per instructions. This project also contains app-compat-v4 and it exports it as set up in Java Build Path -> Order and Export. As per instructions this export Android dependencies and app compat jars.

BUT

My project also uses some old obscure library which need app-compat-v4 and has it in its libs folder. The jar in libs folder of this library is support-v4-19.1.0.jar. An older version that is. It turned out that this library also exports its private libraries (old support) and somehow this takes precedence in my project. So to fix it I had to modify obscure library:

> Java Build Path -> Order and Export -> uncheck Android Private Libraries.